# Using python regular expression to match times

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse a csv file with times in the form of 6:30pm or 7am, or midnight. I've googled around and read the docs for regular expressions in the python docs but haven't been able to implement them successfully.

My first try to match them was:

```
re.findall(r'^d{1,2}(:d{1,2})?$', string)
```

But this didn't work. I have the parenthesis and the question mark there because sometimes there isn't always anything more than the hour. Also, I haven't even begun to think about how to match the am and pm.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not use python's CSV parser? check my answer!

Answer (score 7):

First of all, to match digits you need `\d`, not just `d`.

```
re.findall(r'^\d{1,2}(:\d{1,2})?$', string)
```

Second, as written, your regex will only match a string which is exactly a single time and nothing else, because `^` means "beginning of string" and `$` means "end of string. You can omit those if you want to find all of the times throughout the string:

```
re.findall(r'\d{1,2}(:\d{1,2})?', string)
```

As far as the am/pm goes, you can just add another optional group:

```
re.findall(r'\d{1,2}(:\d{1,2})?(am|pm)?', string)
```

Of course, because everything is optional besides the first 1 or 2 digits, you're also going to match any one or two digit number. You could instead require either at least either am/pm or a colon and two more digits:

```
re.findall(r'\d{1,2}((am|pm)|(:\d{1,2})(am|pm)?)', string)
```

But, findall behaves slightly oddly: if you have matching groups in your pattern, it'll only return the groups rather than the full match. Thus, you can change them to non-matching groups:

```
re.findall(r'\d{1,2}(?:(?:am|pm)|(?::\d{1,2})(?:am|pm)?)', string)
```

Comment: When I use this, it returns only the minutes part of the time, i.e only ':40' when the string is '4:40'.

Comment: Does findall not return the entire matched string? How would I use .groups(0) instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you are strictly looking for a regex solution. You can use:

```
re.findall(r'^\d{1,2}(:\d{1,2})?$', string)
```

---

### But wait

that's not all. There is a better way to do it without regex ;). You can use python **CSV** parsing powers.

```
import csv
string = "November,Monday,6:30pm,1989"
csv_reader = csv.reader( [ string ] )
for row in csv_reader:
    print row
```

Output

```
['November', 'Monday', '6:30pm', '1989']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re 
regex = r'(\d{1,2})([.:](\d{1,2}))?[ ]?(am|pm)?' 
groups = re.findall(regex, value)
```

group1 will give hr 
 
group3 will give min 
 
group4 will give am/pm

Examples : 
12pm 
12.30pm 
12:30pm 
2.30 am 
all these examples are working