# How can I make a newline under the condition-matching number?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

How can I use the loop to make newlines under every date and time like '08-29' and '10:15',in order to separate the result from parts to each other.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1"}
all_url = 'https://www.smm.cn/'
start_html = requests.get(all_url,
                          headers=headers)
Soup = BeautifulSoup(start_html.text, 'lxml')
alltd = Soup.find('div', class_='box-body').find_all('tbody')
for td in alltd:
    title = td.get_text()
    j = title.split()

for b in j:
    print(b)
```

Comment: Can you show some of your input data?

Comment: Now the data like
`SMM
1#电解铜
52500-52700
52600
300
08-29
升贴水
(贴)100
-
(贴)50
-75
20
11:30
洋山铜溢价(仓单)
62.00-72.00
67.00
0
08-29
洋山铜溢价(提单)
55.00-65.00
60.00
0
08-29
SMM
A00铝
16050-16090
16070
10
08-29
升贴水
(贴)220
-
(贴)180
-200
0
10:15
SMM
1#铅
19200-19350
19275
100
08-29`

Comment: @KinsLau if the answer is correct, please don't forget to upvote the answer and mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't fully get what you meant but if you want to print a line after each date shown you can use this code:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1"}
all_url = 'https://www.smm.cn/'
start_html = requests.get(all_url,
                      headers=headers)
Soup = BeautifulSoup(start_html.text, 'lxml')
alltd = Soup.find('div', class_='box-body').find_all('tbody')
for td in alltd:
    title = td.get_text()
    j = title.split()

for b in j:
    if re.match(r'^\d{2}(-\d{1,2})', b):
        print(b)
        print('\n')
    else:
        print(b)
```

If you need to print line after each date and also after each time, you can replace `if re.match(r'^\d{2}(-\d{1,2})', b):` with `re.match(r'^\d{2}(-\d{1,2})', b) or re.match(r'^\d{1,2}(:\d{1,2})', b)`:

If my answer doesn't fully help you, Probably these links can help:

[Using python regular expression to match times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437207/using-python-regular-expression-to-match-times)

[Basic tutorials for python regular expression](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm)

Good luck my friend!